# Using span in h1 - Can google still find it?

Tags: html, seo

I have recently built 2 websites. Google has no problem finding the first one. However, it seems that the second website doesn't show up very high in Google (even if I search the exact title), but it DOES show up eventually.

I am wondering if the problem could be my h1. I have a span element inside a h1 element, and thought maybe this is the reason google can't find it.

The website is www.radiow.be (dutch) and the specific line of code is:

```
<h1>Radio<span id="title">W</span></h1>
```

So if anyone could help me with this, or tell me this is a problem for Google or not, I'd be very happy.

Comment: `<span>` is a generic inline-level container. It doesn't have any special meaning/semantics. Hence it won't affect the result in search engines.

Comment: I guess questions about SEO are only "off topic" if you specifically mention "SEO"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 0):

No problems in using HTML tags like `<span>`, Google is smart enough to be able to parse the content.

Only problem could arise if you create the HTML on the fly using JavaScript.

The factor which could make your website higher or lower in the SERP (Google results) are connective with your web presence, example:

- Backlinks
- Social Signals
- User Signals
- Brand Factor